# Kotlin: looping through a filtered (possibly empty and at most one element) list

Tags: kotlin, apache-storm

I have a storm bolt that gets tuples which contain a value of type `MyClass`, which in turn carries a time field `startTime`. At the end of the bolt, I'd like to log the time that the processing took from the beginning (marked by `startTime`). So I could do:

```
override fun doExecute(input: Tuple): Boolean {
    ... // my processing logic
    input.values.filterIsInstance(MyClass).forEach {
        val endToEndTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - it.startTime).toInt()
        stats.recordExecutionTime("mytag", endToEndTime)
    }
}
```

I don't really have a problem with this approach. Just cosmetic wise it looks like I could have more than one instance of `MyClass` in the tuple (which I do not). So I was thinking if I could just pick the first out of the list like:

```
override fun doExecute(input: Tuple): Boolean {
    ... // my processing logic
    input.values.filterIsInstance(MyClass).first().let {
        val endToEndTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - it.startTime).toInt()
        stats.recordExecutionTime("mytag", endToEndTime)
    }
}
```

This seems to be more readable. However, if the `filterIsInstance(MyClass)` call returns an empty list, I get an exception by calling `first` on it, while the first solution goes through fine without any exception. Since this is for pure logging purposes, I'd like it to be exception-free.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better way! :)

You can use [`firstOrNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first-or-null.html) and then a safe call:

```
input.values.filterIsInstance(MyClass).firstOrNull()?.let {
    val endToEndTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - it.startTime).toInt()
    stats.recordExecutionTime("mytag", endToEndTime)
}
```

You could also replace the `filterIsInstance` call with the version of `firstOrNull()` that takes a predicate, like so:

```
input.values.firstOrNull { it is MyClass }?.let {ű
    it as MyClass
    val endToEndTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - it.startTime).toInt()
    stats.recordExecutionTime("mytag", endToEndTime)
}
```

Comment: Your first solution works. I had to do one more cast with the 2nd approach as: `(input.values.firstOrNull { it is MyClass }? as MyClass).let...`. Otherwise I can not do `it.startTime` in the `let` block.

Comment: Oops, sorry, you're right. I've fixed my second example with a smart cast. You're probably better off just going with the first one though.